# Width of image changes on carousel click

Tags: html, css

so I've built a carousel slider however I've encountered two problems when I click next slide:

1. The image width changes from 1266 to 760
2. The image drops on the Y axis where half the image is now missing

I have tried changing class names of the images ("carousel__image2", "carousel__image3") but the same issues still occur.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel__track-container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel__image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel__track {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /* position: relative; */
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: red;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__button--left {
  left: -40px;
}

.carousel__button--right {
  right: -40px;
}

.carousel__button img {
  width: 12px;
}

.carousel__nav {
  background: violet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.carousel__indicator {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel__indicator.current-slide {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--left is-hidden">
          <img src="/src/arrow-left.png" alt="" height="10px">
        </button>
  <div class="carousel__track-container">
    <ul class="carousel__track">
      <li class="carousel__slide current-slide"><img class="carousel__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1266x500" alt=""></li>
      <li class="carousel__slide"><img class="carousel__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1266x500" alt=""></li>
      <li class="carousel__slide"><img class="carousel__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1266x500" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel__button carousel__button--right">
          <img src="/src/arrow-right.png" alt="" height="10px">
        </button>

  <div class="carousel__nav">
    <button class="carousel__indicator current-slide"></button>
    <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
    <button class="carousel__indicator"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a [mcve] - please change the images to something that reflects your issue. You can get images from placeholder.com

Comment: I've added some placeholder images

Answer (score 0):

Change your .carousel__image class to something like below.

```
.carousel__image {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should take care of y-axis
This would make your image responsive to varying screen heights.